# JQuery attach focus event to the next focused input

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

The idea here is that a function needs to run only the on next focus of any input/textarea/select, but one-time function can be reset to run again.

A simple example would be that a checkbox was selected, then on the next focus event on any other field should run a check to see if that field has a specific attribute value (with more than one possible fields being true). This should allow the user to deselect the checkbox, then select the checkbox again to have the same event fire again.

It is worth noting that testing if the checkbox is selected is not an option, since this attached focus event should have the ability to set from a blur, click, or any other jQuery event for any type of field.

My current idea is to set a global JavaScript variable that is checked on every focus event:

`var checkFocus = false;`

Then, set focus events for all form fields, including input, textarea, etc.:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
  if(checkFocus){
    // Put the target code here.
    checkFocus = false;
  }
});
```

This will allow any part of the code to set checkFocus to true, and subsequently tell the focus events to run the target code.

Is there a way to catch all focus events for every element? And if so, is there a way to run a one-time-only event that can also be set to run once more if required?

**EDIT**

There is a way to make a focus event a one-time-only event, but this doesn't include any form fields that are not input element, like a textarea or select. This can be done with the `off(event)` function. I'm not sure if this is helpful at all for this question, since doing this for other selectors will actually make the code occur more than once.

```
$("input").on("focus", function(event) {
  alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
  $(this).off(event);
});
```

Comment: Do you just want to execute something on focus of an element if a radio is checked..? or something else?

Comment: Yes, but the value of the radio should be irrelevant to the target code within the focus event.

Comment: Something to play with is using jQuery's one() to attach a handler and attach again in inside the handler if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive Google searches, I was able to answer my own question...

This is how you would set the event (which is possible to be set anywhere):

```
var id = 'something';
var name = 'something-else';

// Bind the event to three tags commonly used on forms
$("input, select, textarea").on("focus", {id: id, name: name}, focusEvent);
```

This is the `focusEvent` function that would handle the logic on a field focus:

```
var focusEvent = function(event){
  // Commonly used values for an event
  var id = event.data.id;
  var name = event.data.name;
  var focused_id = $(this).attr('id');
  var focused_name = $(this).attr('name');

  // Do something on the next focus event

  // Unbind the one-time event
  $("input, select, textarea").off("focus", focusEvent);
}
```

This was the easiest setup I could come up with that did not require a global variable nor setting multiple events that needed to be handled individually.

The one part that is not originally included in the question is the ability of `.on()` function to pass arguments to a defined event function using `event.data`. This ended up making my life a whole lot easier when writing the focus event logic.

Also, the great thing about this solution is that the event can be unbound depending on the logic of the event function. This gives the ability to turn the one-time-event into a possibly-one-time-event.